# Moles exited with code -1002, how can I know what happen to it?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, moles, pex

I'm using Pex and Moles 0.94.51023.0 with VS2010 SP1.
I have successfully made some Moles type of some Assembly reference and tested some cases.
But this time with another reference, Moles has an error:

```
Error   3   The command ""C:\Program Files\Microsoft Moles\bin\moles.exe" 
@D:\...\TestProject2\obj\Debug\Moles\moles.args" exited with code -1002.    TestProject2
```

I don't know what is the meaning of 1002. And I search the web, many problems pasted with a very long logs.
How to find the log? And what is 1002?

Thank you.

Comment: OK, I solved this problem myself. Just check the "Output" tab in visual studio. 1002 is a problem with loading assembly. Set the target platform to "Any CPU" of all the assembly reference projects.

Comment: Please post this as an answer, and then accept your answer.  This will help future inquirers easily see the solution. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved this problem myself. Just check the "Output" tab in visual studio. 1002 is a problem with loading assembly. Set the target platform to "Any CPU" of all the assembly reference projects.